# C# Open a web link and wait for a generate file to download

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, web, webclient

I try to download a PDF file from a Tech File Web Generator in C#. If I use WebCLient, I download the source of the page and not the PDF that will be generated.How I can wait for the generate file and download it?

[This is the link](http://pdf.schneider-electric.nu/download.aspx?type=partnumbers&file=LC1BL31F22_document.pdf&salesorgid=21&dist=0&lang=1&render=eShopV3&TemplateID=1)